# How to play spore without a code?

Tags: spore

So recently I bought a physical copy of Spore from a thrift store but when I opened it it only contained the disk. Can I play spore without a code?

Comment: What happens when you insert the disk in your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no clean official way around this. You need a valid CD key to install the game. I've seen some forum posts online advocating talking to EA directly to try and secure a new key, but I haven't found any successful results.

Now, of course, there are a slew of less-than-official means to secure a CD key or play the game without one, but those are beyond the purview of this site.

Answer (score 0):

While EA are not obliged to give you a new key, if you start a live chat or call EA support and kindly explain the situation there's a good chance they will supply you with a new key, however if the agent you reach isn't in a good mood and says "there's nothing we can do"

Return to the store and explain the situation, the store is obliged to give you a full refund!